# Symfony 3.4: how to make form validation and get results associated to each field?

Tags: symfony

Entity:

```php
class Meeting
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    //......etc
}
```

Form:

```php
class MeetingType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('desctiption', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('avatar', FileType::class)
            ->add('beginAt', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('createdAt', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('updatedAt', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('uid', IntegerType::class)
            ;
    }
}
```

Controller/Action where I try to handle data sended by XHR:

```php
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $formData = [
       //... some data transformation code here
       //... and CSRF-token adding
    ];
    $form = $this->createForm(MeetingType::class, new Meeting);
    $form->submit($formData);
    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        $errors = [];
               foreach ($form->getErrors(true, false) as $key => $error) {
                    if (method_exists($error, 'getMessage')) {
                        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
                    } else {
                        foreach ($error as $k => $e) {
                            $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new JsonResponse([
                    'success' => false,
                    'errors' => $errors,
                    'type' => 'form-validation',
                ]);
    }
}
```

The problem: I get strange behavior, when I added constraints inside `buildForm` or inside the entity (using `loadValidatorMetadata`) it makes no effect. But the code you can see above generates errors: *The value must not be empty* though it has no validation rules.

Comment: Even if I don't have a solution for your problem at hand: keep in mind that Symfony 3.4 is pretty outdated. It has left all kinds of support in Nov 2021

Comment: @NicoHaase this is legacy I must support